# Run C# integration tests with a configurable variable locally and as a part of a VSTS build

Tags: c#, azure-devops, integration-testing, entity-framework-core

I have a test project within my solution that can run tests on a live sql database.  The problem is I have to provide the connection string for it to connect to the database.

Is there anyway that I can provide a different connection string specified in the Visual Studio Online Build Parameters/Variables? I've looked into creating an appsettings.json file to but I'm still not sure how to override the value in appsettings.json.

It might be important to note that my test project is testing EF Core SqlServer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get this working.  I added an `appsettings.json` file and changed the property *Copy to Output Directory* to **Copy Always**.  I then an abstract class called DbTests with a setup method

*appsettings.json*

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "TestDatabase": "YOUR CONNECTION STRING GOES HERE"
  }
}
```

*DbTests.cs* (snippet)

```
// ...

IConfigurationRoot configurationRoot = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
    .AddEnvironmentVariables()  // <== this is important
    .Build();

string connectionString = configurationRoot.GetConnectionString("TestDatabase")

// ...
```

The `.AddEnvironmentVariables()` allows me to override variables contained in the `appsettings.json` with environment variables.  I can set environment variables within VSTS

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Proceeding with `appsettings.json` or a `config` file is the correct approach. What you need in addition is the [Tokenizer](https://github.com/openalm/Extension-UtilitiesPack) build task that will replace the connection string with the value of a VSO variable.

In the configuration file (`appsettings.json`), provide the value as `__SQLConnectionString__` for the connection string property. Then, in the build VSO variable, add a variable with the name `SQLConnectionString`. Whatever value you provide for this variable, the Tokenizer task will replace the `__SQLConnectionString__` with this value.

Comment: How would you be able to run the tests locally?